# Search a String out of a JSON file or JSObject file by selecting a name or id or email

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I still dont understand, so i try to Change my question to a better.

I am having a Json or JS Object like this:

[{"id":1,"nick":"einsA","email":"einsB","passwort":"einsC","freundschaften":[]},{"id":2,"nick":"finkN","email":"finkE","passwort":"finkP","freundschaften":[]},{"id":3,"nick":"Fink3","email":"Fink33","passwort":"Fink333","freundschaften":[]}]

this came out of a JS / Ajax Code snipet:

function dearchUser(){

```
   var obj;

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/CustomerManagementWeb/api/v1/customers/liste", 
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            var mitglied = data;
            var myData = JSON.parse(mitglied);              
            //document.write(data);


        }
    });


}
```

and my aim is to select the "nick" in order to receive the whole string: 
id / nick / email / Password. I only want to receive 1 data record out of many, because the nick is unique.

I know that i have to iterate over the JS Object, but i do not know how i can find out how many records are in this file, And I dont know how can i select this 1 data record (per nick) in order to work with it further, for example an comparison if this nick already exists or not. / or an authorisation against this JS file / JSON.

Maybe a stupid question, but i realy wand to understand and learn this (Basics!)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Do some research around basic JavaScript syntax, including array syntax (e.g., the `[` and `]` that surround your JSON), loops, etc.. Stack Overflow is really not a site for tutorials on the basics; there are plenty of sites out there on the world wide web that can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in an array called `data` then you can find your record by using the find method 

`data.find(item => item.nick === 'einsB')`

You can read more about the `find` method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: mmmh, I dont think it is an Array. It is a JavaScript Object. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The data that you have in the question description is an array. `[{"id":1,"nick":"einsA","email":"einsB","passwort":"einsC","freundschaften":[]},{"id":2,"nick":"finkN","email":"finkE","passwort":"finkP","freundschaften":[]},{"id":3,"nick":"Fink3","email":"Fink33","passwort":"Fink333","freundschaften":[]}]` and each item in the array is a JS object